# Append a child element before the last child

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can't make this work like my expected result, would you please give me any suggestions?

***Note: this work, if I run it from console, but it doesn't from link function.***

`angular.element('ul.dropdown-user li:last').before('<li class="divider"></li>');`

***Items:***

```
[
{
    label: 'User profile',
    link : '#',
    icon : 'user'
},
{
    label: 'Setting',
    link : '#',
    icon : 'gear'
},
{
    label : 'Logout',
    link : '#',
    icon : 'sign-out'
}]
```

***Template:***

```
$templateCache.put("template/dropdown-user.html",
    '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">'+
        '<li ng-repeat="item in items">'+
            '<a href="{{item.link}}"><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}} fa-fw"></i> {{item.label}}</a>'+
        '</li>'+
    '</ul>'
)
```

***Directive:***

```
.directive('navbarMenuUserItem',[function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'template/dropdown-user.html',
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            items: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
             //It doesn't work
             angular.element('ul.dropdown-user li:last').before('<li class="divider"></li>');

             //Any suggestion, please?
        }
    }
}])
```

***Expected result:***

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user ng-isolate-scope" items="usermenu">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>User profile</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Setting</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="ng-binding"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, when you call

```
angular.element('ul.dropdown-user li:last').before('<li class="divider"></li>');
```

angular does not render the view yet. In fact, we should not do DOM manipulation inside the link function like this.

Try adding 1 more object to be rendered as divider:

```
[{
    label: 'User profile',
    link: '#',
    icon: 'user'
  }, {
    label: 'Setting',
    link: '#',
    icon: 'gear'
  }, 
  {
    isDivider:true
    },{
    label: 'Logout',
    link: '#',
    icon: 'sign-out'
  }];
```

Modify your template code to like this using `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
    <li ng-repeat-start="item in items" ng-if="!item.isDivider">
       <a href="{{item.link}}"><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}} fa-fw"></i> {{item.label}}       </a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat-end class="divider" ng-if="item.isDivider">

    </li>
</ul>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/mg6rqdUy9tZnONrWwgkI?p=preview)